# How to inject a service in a api conext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have a api context and I have a service. And I try to write the logic in each of the components.

So I have the service:

```
const CategoryService = () => {
    

    const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:19000/animal/categories/main_groups/", {
                method: "GET",
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
            }

            return await response.json();
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
            throw error;
        }
    };

    return fetchCategoryData;
};

export default CategoryService;
```

and I have the context:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const CategoryContext = createContext();

const CategoryContextProvier = (props) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const value = {
        categoryList,
        loading,
        setCategoryList,
        setLoading,
    };

    return <CategoryContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</CategoryContext.Provider>;
};

export default CategoryContextProvier;
```

Question: how to communicate these two witch each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just call fetchCategoryData in CategoryContextProvier useEffect
like this

```
const CategoryContextProvier = (props) => {
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const value = {
        categoryList,
        loading,
        setCategoryList,
        setLoading,
    };
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        setLoading(true);
        fetchCategoryData()
           .then(res=> setCategoryList(res))
           .finally(()=> setLoading(false));
    },[]) 

    return <CategoryContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</CategoryContext.Provider>;
};
```